# Displaying data in two columns using the Mod command to alternate between them

Tags: asp-classic

I have a table that I want data in. The data will be from a database and sorted by id. Here is the raw table and how I want it to display.

I am using classic ASP.
I used to know how to do this using mod 2 but two strokes later, and it's gone.
Here is a simple table of how it should look.

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="5" class="auto-style1">
    <tr>
        <td>Player 1</td>
        <td>VS</td>
        <td>Player 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The numbers represent id field.

I am all too familiar with displaying rows but I have never tried displaying across two columns.

I have read about using mod 2 but I am just not grasping how to implement it into a table.

Comment: Oh hold up .. why don't you just look into Bootstrap?  The divs are based on the total value of 12 .. so splitting it in half would be 6 so you could do something like this:
<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'>FIRST COL</div><div class='col-md-6'>SECOND COL</div></div>

and that would split it in half much easier than dealing with td and tr situations.

Comment: Yes, I am able to create the recordset without any issues. I just want it to display across two columns instead of 1 row per record.

Comment: I have used the mod 2 way of doing it in the past, but just forget how to due to a stroke.

Comment: Well all i remember about that is, mod means its divisible by a number, so that way you can tell if its even or odd, and if its even its the second column side sort of thing.   
 That is the premise, just alternate back and forth.  I've been forced to make my apps work on phones and PCs and laptops so Bootstrap is the solution i use so i don't have to write the code 20 different times for all the possible formats.

Comment: x = number mod number  is the format to use mod ...  The concept you want is something like a For x = 1 to 2 , and if its not able to mod by x then you are on 1 and if it is able to mod by x you are on x = 2 if that makes sense .. good luck.

Comment: One tip would be to build a stored procedure so you can get the SELECT you need but also do another COUNT statement before or after it so you know how many records you are dealing with.  Unless you know how to use GetRows, then you could just get the Ubound of the Array and do a For/Next loop going from x = 0 to Array(Ubound) and that way you can use the Ubound to know how many records you have so you can use that mod trick to figure out some math.  I still don't know that you need to use mod, but I know it can be used.

Comment: But the only way I could think it could be used is to calculate if a number is able to divide by another number and throws true or false, and if you can use that to figure out how many columns you need, neat.  But seems you could just count how many you need based on your recordset count and just loop that many times  build both sides on each pass .. does that make sense?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS MAXCOUNT FROM TABLE WHERE PKEY = 1;   Lets say it pulls 30 records, you could just do FOR x = 0 to MAXCOUNT  (HTML CODE to create both rows) NEXT ... this would not require you to do math to calculate IF or IF NOT a number is divisible by another, that trick can work and does work, but its extra steps in this case.

Comment: I thought mod 2 would be the easiest method to use. This would make the odd number rows be in the left column, and the even be on the right. I just wish I could remember how to allow the <tr> and <td> assign as a result of the mod 2 result. 

I guess I could use two sql statements in the different <td> using step 2. This may be the easiest way to go until I remember the other way.

Comment: Something like if value = 1 then (left side code) else (right side code)  And mod is used in this format RESULT = number mod number

Comment: This code is for something else, but I found something in some example scripts using mod to alternate in a table (this one was for a chess board but maybe this snippet will help you.

For Each Row in Table.Rows
   For Each Cell in Row.Cells
      ' set background on cells which sum of indices is odd
      If (Cell.Index + Row.Index) Mod 2 = 1 Then
         Cell.BgColor = "brown"
      End if

      Piece = Pieces( 8 * (Row.Index - 1) + Cell.Index )
      Cell.AddText ChrW(Piece), "size=20; indentx=1; indenty=1"
   Next
Next

Comment: Note though I don't think the Table.Cell or Table.Row command works be default as it was updated with the pdf generation package I got, but I saw the use of Mod in it and wanted to toss this at you in hopes you could get a glimmer of help from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for anyone following or just wants to know:

```
<%
SET ROWCNT = CONN.EXECUTE("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CNT1 FROM SINGLES1") CNT1 = ROWCNT("CNT1")

iITEMSPerRow = 2 iItems = CINT(cnt1)

strDISPLAY = ""

For i = 1 to iItems

If i mod iITEMSPerRow = 1 Then strDISPLAY = strDISPLAY & "<tr>"

strDISPLAY = strDISPLAY & "<td>" & i & "</td>"

If i mod iITEMSPerRow = 0 Then strDISPLAY = strDISPLAY & "</tr>"
Next

strDISPLAY = strDISPLAY & ""

Response.write(strDISPLAY) %>
```